# Submit a form with ja/jQuery and stay at same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

the title is what i need. i found some questions with my problem but didn't help.

there is my code

```
var confirmSave = confirm('Save;');
if(confirmSave){
    $('.redirected_form').submit( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            succes: function( data ) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');                         
                    },
            error: function(){
                       alert('Something wrong');
                   }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

this code wont save anything

with this

```
var confirmSave = confirm('Αποθήκευση ραντεβού;');
if(confirmSave){
    document.getElementById("date_form_submit").click();
    $('.redirected_form').submit( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                         $('#myModal').modal('hide');                        
                     },
            error: function(){
                       alert('Something wrong');
                   }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

data saved but redirected to PHP page...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check your jquery library i think one of this problem is your jquery path make sure it is in the head tag in html

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   var form = document.getElementById("formid");
                    formdata2 = new FormData(form);

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "php file",
                        cache : false,
                        contentType : false,
                        processData : false,
                        data : formdata2,
                        type : "post",
                        success : function(data) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.redirected_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');                         
                      },
            error   : function(){
                         alert('Something wrong');
                      }
        });
});
```

Comment: @NinjTsax check the updated answer, i added `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, on confrim, trigger form submit. Also, have the form submit hander as an independent block (and not inside the confirm condition) as below.

```
var confirmSave = confirm('Αποθήκευση ραντεβού;');

if(confirmSave) {
    $('.redirected_form').submit();
}

$('.redirected_form').submit(function(e) {

    //e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : $(this).attr('method'),
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');                         
        },
        error   : function(){
            alert('Something wrong');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should actually work. But, without seeing your HTML it's hard to say what's wrong. I've added `return false;` and it should now work as long as `jQuery` is loaded onto the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are posting data in two ways at once.

Two solutions:

1. You don't have to use the form's submit feature. It is enough to just define a click handler on a button (not submit typed), which will perform the AJAX call with your serialized data, and not reloads the page.
   If you want to use the serialize() method, i suggest using the ID attribute to select the form which you want to serialize, and perform the method on it.
2. You could even call the preventDefault() method of the event object (you haven't got that in your code, but it could be received in your submit event handler), therefore the form would not be posted by the traditional way, so no reload would happen.

But this second way is not recommended at all. Since you are using AJAX, you should do that without submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you make me think more all of you with your answers.
Thanks for help, the problem solved with that code

```
var confirmSave = confirm('Save;');
                    if(confirmSave)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("date_form_submit").click();
                    }
```

and in different script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.redirected_form').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');                         
                      },
            error   : function(){
                         alert('Something wrong');
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

im new to js jQuery and i cant explain why that happens.

Thanks all for your answers